# How to use statemnts in as criteria in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, ms-access-2013

I have a table and a query to find specific rows from the table. The table contains a column called `DueDate` which contains a date as a short text. In some cases due date is not applicable so for some situations it contains the string "N/A". What I want to do is the use the expression Expr1:
 `DateDiff("m";CDate([DueDate]);Date())` in a where statement with a criteria <1. But for the NA fields it gives errors. How can I handle this. Is it possible to use iif statements in criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IIf` expressions in a `WHERE` clause, but I suggest you consider this `Switch` expression instead.  It returns False when `DueDate = 'N/A'`, True when the `DateDiff` expression returns a value less than 1 month, and Null otherwise.

```sql
WHERE Switch
    (
        DueDate = 'N/A', False,
        DateDiff('m',CDate([DueDate]),Date()) < 1, True
    ) = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter those record with

```
where DueDate <> 'N/A'
```